# Cron entry executed twice

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I have the following crontab entry

```
*/59 * * * *  php insights/page >> crontab-insights-page.log 2>&1
```

Inside action, I echo date , and getting the following pattern

---- Starting Insights Cron Job on 2020-06-21 16:59:01 ----

---- Starting Insights Cron Job on 2020-06-21 17:00:01 ----

Its being fired twice, just one minute after!

Running
`ps -axjf | grep cron`

Shows **only one** running process *cron* from the only user **root**

What is happening???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*/59` means divisible by 59. 0 and 59 are both divisible by 59. Just remove the `*/`.